# function in function async loop

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm going to call the unspecified number of the counter function from inside the loop function
And the counter function also call the send_request function

just i want counter do not wait for the send_request answer , when HTTP response Arrived print

```
import requests
import asyncio
import random 


async def counter(i):
    print("Started counter ",i)
    await asyncio.create_task(send_request(random.randint(1,10)))
                                   
async def send_request(i):
    print("Sending HTTP request  ",i)
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    r = requests.get('http://example.com')
    print(f"Got HTTP response with status {r.status_code} in time {i}")

@app.incomeing_msg(i)
async def loop(i):
    asyncio.create_task(counter(i))
        
asyncio.run(loop())
```

Comment: Use an asynchronous HTTP library like https://docs.aiohttp.org/en !

Comment: @KlausD. `This page does not exist yet.`

Comment: If you don't want ``loop`` to wait for each task, don't ``await`` each task! ``gather`` them once you have created all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does `await asyncio.create_task()` behave different then when assigning it to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706978/why-does-await-asyncio-create-task-behave-different-then-when-assigning-it-t)

Comment: Note that ``requests`` is a *synchronous* library. Don't use it in an *asynchronous* event loop, since it will block the entire loop – and thus all its tasks – while working.

Comment: My English is not good and I could not explain it correctly..  

requests do not matter and replace everything..  

It is important that these requests are sent quickly through the loop to the counter .. ..  and from the counter to send_request ..  

counter do not wait for the send_request answer

Answer (score -1):

BTW if you want to send `n` `requests` in parallel you can use `threading` and write something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
import random
import time


def counter(i):
    print("Started counter ", i)
    send_request(random.randint(1, 10))


def send_request(i):
    print("Sending HTTP request  ", i)
    time.sleep(i)
    r = requests.get('http://example.com')
    print(f"Got HTTP response with status {r.status_code} in time {i}")


def loop():
    n = 5 
    tasks = [Thread(target=counter, args=(i, )) for i in range(n)]
    [t.start() for t in tasks]
```

Comment: That's right- this is exactly what I need.  just async version